# OSX with Qt3D 5.12.2 and QML, SceneLoader: Found no suitable importer plugin for 3ds obj

Tags: macos, qt, qml

I installed the most recent version of Qt5 - 5.12.2 for macOS and tried to create an application with `SceneLoader` object for loading my scenes. It does not work no matter what format I pass to it, I always have this error:

> Found no suitable importer plugin for

I also can't find any examples in my `/Users/user/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.12.2/qt3d`  (it is where I have Qt installed) regarding **assimp** but according to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-attribution-assimp.html) it must be there.

It also worth mentioning, that even though `SceneLoader` does not open anything (and `*.obj` as well), I am able to open them using `Mesh` object and then render them myself.

What have I done wrong? Do I need to install anything else in order to make it work? I tried to find in the components anything related to 3d or assimp and everything was ticked there, however, I was not able to find examples.

[Crosspost on qt forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/101662/osx-with-qt3d-5-12-2-and-qml-sceneloader-found-no-suitable-importer-plugin-for-3ds-obj)
[Crosspost on bugreports.qt.io](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-75145)

Answer (score 3):

As of this writing, the above error seems to be a known bug that has been reported but not resolved yet.
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89045

The `libassimpsceneimport.so` library file seems to be missing, which helps with loading various 3D file formats.

There's a hacky workaround to avoid the "found no suitable..." error. Using Qt Maintenance, install Qt 5.15.1. Next, copy the `Qt->5.15.1->gcc_64->plugins->sceneparsers->libassimpsceneimport.so` file to the corresponding 'sceneparsers' folder in the Qt 5.15.2 installation directory.